# How do I authenticate (bind) to ldaps using username and password with the ldap3 crate?

Tags: rust, ldap

I am searching for a way to supply the username and password while connecting to ldaps.
The examples on the documentation page for crate ldap3 seem not illustrate supplying username and password while binding to ldap.

```
//taken from https://docs.rs/crate/ldap3/0.9.3
use ldap3::{LdapConn, Scope, SearchEntry};
use ldap3::result::Result;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut ldap = LdapConn::new("ldap://localhost:2389")?;
    let (rs, _res) = ldap.search(
        "ou=Places,dc=example,dc=org",
        Scope::Subtree,
        "(&(objectClass=locality)(l=ma*))",
        vec!["l"]
    )?.success()?;
    for entry in rs {
        println!("{:?}", SearchEntry::construct(entry));
    }
    Ok(ldap.unbind()?)
}
```

Comment: Why can't you add it in the connection string? `LdapConn::new(format!("ldap://{}:{}@localhost:2389", USER, PASS))`

Comment: You can authenticate the user with `ldap.simple_bind(bind_dn, bind_pw)` as stated [here](https://docs.rs/ldap3/0.6.1/ldap3/struct.LdapConn.html#method.simple_bind), didn't find any example though..

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution that I got working on my own project, I hope it helps:

```
use ldap3::{LdapConnAsync, LdapConnSettings};

// Pass in username and password to authenticate against LDAP
async fn authenticate(username: &str, password: &str) -> bool {
    // Connection to the LDAP Server
    let (conn, mut ldap) =
        LdapConnAsync::with_settings(LdapConnSettings::new()
                                         .set_starttls(true)
                                         .set_no_tls_verify(true),
                                     "ldap://localhost:2389").await.unwrap();
    ldap3::drive!(conn);

    // Takes the username provided and converts it into an email for validation
    // This is required because LDAP uses either the Distinguished name or Email in order to bind. Username alone will not work :/
    let email = format!("{}@domain.com", username);

    // Attempts a simple bind using the passed in values of username and Password
    let result = ldap.simple_bind(email.as_str(), password).await.unwrap().success();
    ldap.unbind().await.unwrap();

    // If the authentication is successful return true, else return false.
    if !result.is_err() {
        true
    } else { false }
}
```

Comment: Do we require setup a cacert file like java?

Comment: Could you give a example main()? seems the result can not easy show by println("{:?}")

Comment: @DanielYCLin
Nothing else is needed. In main() pass the username and password as a static string/string slice.

The authenticate() Method will return a bool of 'true' if the username and password combination exists in LDAP and a bool of 'false' if they do not exist or the password is incorrect

Comment: I'm a newbie in rust. So, the problem is caused by the async keyword which make the my main function can not work. And I don't know how to proper wait the async function end.

Comment: @DanielYCLin add ".await" to the end of the authenticate function wherever you call it. Alternatively, you can remove the async altogether.

Comment: `async fn main() { authenticate("use", "pass").await; }`  compile failed as " `main` function is not allowed to be `async`"

Comment: @DanielYCLin Move the async fn out of main into its own function. Call the function from main with a ".await" at the end.

I would copy and paste the code above below the main function. and inside of the main function put, "let success = authenticate('username here', 'password here').await;"

Comment: `fn main() { let success = authenticate("use", "pass").await;}` will show error message for `await` `only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks`

Comment: @DanielYCLin use the Tokio crate: https://crates.io/crates/tokio - to make your main function async. Add the dependency and then above your main function add, "#[tokio::main]" also in front of your main function make sure to add the work "async"

Comment: `async fn main() { authenticate("usr", "pass").await; }` and it works now.